# Android: Changing the start voice recognition of PochetSphinix

Tags: android

Following the guide on the official website:
http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/05/building-pocketsphinx-on-android/

I managed to install the example on my device.

Now I'd like to change the following code:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        start_date = new Date();
        this.listening = true;
        this.rec.start();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        Date end_date = new Date();
        long nmsec = end_date.getTime() - start_date.getTime();
        this.speech_dur = (float)nmsec / 1000;
        if (this.listening) {
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Showing Dialog");
            this.rec_dialog = ProgressDialog.show(PocketSphinxDemo.this, "", "Recognizing speech...", true);
            this.rec_dialog.setCancelable(false);
            this.listening = false;
        }
        this.rec.stop();
        break;
    default:
        ;
    }
    /* Let the button handle its own state */
    return false;
}
```

so that you do not have to use the click on the button to start voice recognition, that recognition be started when you start talking and stop immediately after you finish speaking.

This is possible? I hope there is someone that I can help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible but a bit longer.

Instead of the button, wait for the beginning of an input from the microphone and wait till the moment when there is no input. That can be used as an input.

Basically, you need a piece of code that will run continuously till an input is obtained. Run this in a separate thread and use conditional statements/a timed loop(use a thread) to fetch the input.
Use a flag to come out of the loop or continue in the loop.

Hope I got your requirement right and I hope I was able to help you.

Comment: It is with this in principle was also my idea .. I wanted to have a confirmation that it was a way possible, thanks! My only puzzlement was in fact due to background noise, because if I run the start of recognition in this way, then in practice the recognition could start even if I'm not talking, or worse if I'm talking about and when I finish talking c 'background noise is a strong practical recognition abbastamnza not gonna stop being right?
Would you have any ideas on how to avoid this? Thanks again for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah.. That is possible. Background noise can be taken care of. But that might need specialized APIs and some really good coding.

Try this. As soon as you start the thread to fetch the input, display a notification for few seconds, say 3-4 seconds, which asks the user to wait. In this few seconds, you must detect the background noise that is available and calculate the mean strength and other characteristics of this noise. Then, close the notification and read the input. Check the strength of the input with noise measurement which you obtained. If it is same or lower it is just noise or the input isn't loud/clear enough. So, ask the user to speak louder/clearly. Once you get the input, try to filter the noise using an API that can do it and that clears up the signal and it is ready to be detected.

This is essentially an engineering work and very easy in a DSP with MATLAB. Hope my idea works in Android and I really hope that I didn't confuse you.

But in Android, you will need an specialized API or may be Android comes with something which can help you here. I haven't done anything like this before. So I'm able to give the precise commands that can help you, in case there is any.

Hope I was able to help you.